# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `categoria_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Controlador**

```
def index
        @categorias = Categoria.all
end

def new
        @categoria = Categoria.new
end

def create
        @categoria = Categoria.new(campo_params)  
          if @categoria.save
            return redirect_to(categorias_path)
          else
            render :new
          end
end
```

**Route**

`resources :categorias`

**Vista**

```
<%= form_for @categoria do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :elemento %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :elemento %>

  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :clave %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :clave %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :valor %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :valor %>
  </p>


<% end %>
```

**Vista index**

```
 <%= button_to("Añadir", new_categoria_path() , method: :get) %>
```

**Error**

```
undefined method `categoria_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x3a0eb88>:0x6aeb1c0>
Did you mean?  categoria_path
```

Cuando me crea la instancia en el metodo New y me manda a la vista me salta el error, si quito el formulario y pongo cualquier cosa funciona El flujo es el siguiente:

Pincho en el botón crear, se va al metodo New del controlador, crea la instancia y me manda a la Vista new.html.erb, yo ahí miro lo que le llega por parámetro y le llaga la instancia

Answer (score 1):

En el stacktrace del error (agrégalo completo para la próxima) debe decir el archivo y la línea donde se está generando el error.
En alguna parte de tu código estás llamando a `categoria_index_path`, cuando debería ser `categorias_path`.